# How to get an ace of hearts?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, card-games

A card is drawn at random from a pack of $52$. According to the value of this card ($A =1, J=Q=K=10$) as many further cards are drawn. What is the probability that the ace of hearts is among those drawn(including the first card)? [Answer = $5/34$]

I tried splitting it up into 2 parts: 
Part 1 for the ace: It can either be the ace of hearts at first which is $(1/4)(51/52)$ or ace of hearts second ${^4}C_3\cdot 1/51$. But I can't seem to get the answer please help.

Comment: What are the rules of drawing?

Comment: No replacement and as specified according to the value

Comment: "as specified according to the value" I cannot say that I´ve understood this rule. When you stop and why?

Comment: So you draw one card if it's an ace you draw one more card and stop if it's a j q or k you draw 10 more and stop

Comment: This comment you should write into the question. You´ve omitted this crucial information. You shouldn´t be surprised that nobody can answer your question without these information.

Comment: After reading it several times it is still unclear. Post the exercise word by word.

Comment: The original post is the exercise word for word

Comment: After reading carefully again it is now clear what is meant.

Comment: Do you have a possible answer? or explanation?

Comment: Not really. My attempts are too complicated and lead to nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting the problem is a good idea.

**1)** A heart is drawn first. There a two cases

**a)** Ace of hearts: $\frac1{52} \quad (\color{blue}{I})$

We are done.

**b)** An ace of not hearts and then the ace of hearts: $\frac3{52}\cdot \frac1{51}  \quad (\color{blue}{II})$

**2)**

We can draw the number $2$ ($k=2$) and then draw two cards where one of them is the ace of hearts. The probability is

$$\frac4{52}\cdot \frac{\binom{1}{1}\cdot \binom{50}{1}}{\binom{51}{2}}$$

We can sum up the probabilities from $k=2$ to $k=9$

$$\frac4{52}\cdot \left( \sum_{k=2}^9\frac{\binom{1}{1}\cdot \binom{50}{k-1}}{\binom{51}{k}}\right)  \quad (\color{blue}{III})$$

**3)** What is left where we have to draw 10 after the first draw. This is the case when we have drawn a $10$, Jack, Queen or King.

We have $k=10$ and regard the $4$ cases by multiplying it by $4$

$$4\cdot \frac4{52}\cdot \frac{\binom{1}{1}\cdot \binom{50}{9}}{\binom{51}{10}} \quad (\color{blue}{IV})$$

What is left is to sum up the intermediate results: $ (\color{blue}{I})+ (\color{blue}{II})+(\color{blue}{III})+(\color{blue}{IV})$

Especially for the third term a calculator is needed. Here is what I got as the [final result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(4*((50)%20choose%20(10-1))%2F((51)%20choose%2010)*4%2F52%2B1%2F52%2B3%2F52*1%2F51)%2B4%2F52*sum_(k%3D2)%5E9%20((50)%20choose%20(k-1))%2F((51)%20choose%20k)). It is the proposed solution.

Comment: There are only three aces of not hearts. The probability in 1b should be $\frac{3}{52} \cdot \frac{1}{51}$. The final result is correct.

Comment: @KoenTiels Good catch. Thank your very much. I´ve edited the typo.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: @KombatWombat You´re welcome.

Comment: Observation: ${50 \choose k-1}  / {51 \choose k} = k / 51$ which also has the easy explanation as the ace of hearts being in the next $k$ cards out of $51$.  Question: obviously the answer reduces to $5/34$ but *why*?  This is such a simple fraction that I keep thinking there might be an alternate proof...  or is it just a coincidence?  :(

Comment: @antkam Good observation with the fraction of the binomial coefficients. Then it might be possible to calculate it by hand-without making a mistake. But I don´t think that there is a simpler proof since the problem is not symmetric.

Comment: I may have missed something but shouldn't case (1) be "An ace is drawn first"? Otherwise, (1)(b) implies you've drawn an ace of not hearts from a card that's a heart...

Comment: @Paul Yeah, at (1) I meant "ace heart" drawn first.